# Android Studio IDE scripting documentation

Tags: android-studio, ecmascript-6

Where do I find information/documentation on Android Studio IDE Scripting?

The way I understand it, I can use ECMAScript to meddle with the IDE. I would like to able to search through the source code with regex using ECMAScript.